# How to check if a workbook exists in tableau server in python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'd like to publish many `workbooks to tableau server`. When I publish the same workbook again, it will `overwrite` it. What I want is that I'm going to `not publish the same workbook` again `without overwriting it`. Is there any way to do that in python?

Answer (score 1):

Using tabcmd, the publish command has an overwrite option.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#iddf805b62-18ff-4497-9245-adc6905b2084

An example from the documentation:

```
tabcmd publish "analysis_sfdc.hyper" -n "Sales Analysis"
```

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call tabcmd.

That satisfies the question of how to not overwrite a workbook when publishing. If you want to check if the workbook exists, you could do a [tabcmd get](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7e0a0627-ad89-4135-a1c2-85b1d8472568) and check for a 404 error.  I'm not aware of a command that gets a list of all published workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API. See https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Publish_Workbook%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____54.

The REST API allows you to run your python code from a computer separate from the Tableau Server so that your python code isn't competing with Server for CPU cycles.

The REST API includes methods to check if a workbook already exists and to overwrite it. The REST API is very robust and easily used in python code.